# Try to join a OneToOne relationship in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I need some help doing a join using Django, which seems like it should be easy. I have looked at the documentation but it seems like it won't join for some reason.

I am trying to get in my view, the model.Photo and model.PhotoExtended with both joined and then displayed in the view. Currently I am just trying to get the model.Photo displayed but with a join which finds the request.user and filters it based on that.

They are in different apps.

models.py for model.Photo

```
class Photo(ImageModel):
    title = models.CharField(_('title'),
                         max_length=60,
                         unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(_('slug'),
                        unique=True,
                        help_text=_('A "slug" is a unique URL-friendly title for an object.'))
```

models.py for model.PhotoExtended

```
class PhotoExtended(models.Model):

    Photo = models.OneToOneField(Photo, related_name='extended', help_text='Photo required', null=True)

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, help_text='User that uploaded the photo')
```

views.py

```
class PhotoExtendedUserView(ListView):
    template_name = 'photo_user_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.request.user)

        return Photo.objects.filter(photoextended__user=user)
```

Comment: What isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the `related_name` on `Photo` (which shouldn't be capitalized by the way) to `extended` so you need to filter like so:

```
class PhotoExtendedUserView(ListView):
    template_name = 'photo_user_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.request.user)
        # 'extended' vs. 'photoextended'
        return Photo.objects.filter(extended__user=user)
```

Comment: Hi thanks that works great. So why does extended work, but not photoextended? Is it because you have to use the last word on the model?

Comment: The `related_name` argument overrides what term you use, so if you did `models.OneToOneField(Photo, related_name='superawesome')`, you would then filter with `filter(superawesome__user=user)`. The default if you don't use the `related_name` is the name of the class which in your case would be `photoextended`

Comment: I see, I forgot i set that in the model. Thanks a lot!